# Запятая в сложном вопросительном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

> Какое решение было принято и что было положено в его основу?

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении? Вроде как сложное предложение, но запятую не хочется ставить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

И не надо! Предложение действительно сложное, сложносочиненное, но его части объединены вопросительной интонацией, запятая не ставится.

Comment: Это где-нибудь прописано явно?  
По сути - согласен, не хочется тут запятой.

Comment: Во всех учебниках для 11 класса. В академическом справочнике под ред Лопатина - тоже. $  112 п.5 "Запятая  не ставится..., если части ССП представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей частью здесь является интонация..."